# How to make category , sub category and and item detail, download of document in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a worpress website.Website is of selling documents.on homepage there are categories. if i click on any category then new page open.On that page category will appear with its sub category and total results . On results two options appear "download , view". on view click , new page open that is 3rd page or on click download , document will download. How can i achieve it. Can it possible with any plugins. I am using theme http://pixel8es.com/wpthemes/rigel/rigel-corporate/ 
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get it through the wordpress mega menu plugin or by customizing your theme code of that particular page of categories. E.g if you want to show only main categories on your menu you can do it easily, or if you want to show sub categories also on main menu, then you have to create one sub menu inside your main menu.

You can also achive your desired result via editing html code on the particular page.